# Can this integral be evaluated ? If Yes, then How?: $\int_0 ^{\pi/2} e^{\cos(\tan x)}\cos(\sin(\tan x))\space dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0 ^{\pi/2} e^{\cos(\tan x)}\cos(\sin(\tan x))\space dx$$

Please use simple techniques and properties (if possible).

Comment: Mathematica cannot evaluate this analytically. Why would you expect that this is possible?

Comment: It seems impossible…

Comment: Hint: use trigonometric identities to effect $\int_0^{\pi/2}\mapsto\frac14\int_0^{2\pi}$, then use the residue theorem (with $z:=e^{ix}$; be warned $z=\pm i$ require care) to deduce the integral is $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{1/e}\approx2.26928$. As a sanity check, software can approximate this value with a slightly lower upper limit, e.g. [the closest I got with WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+e%5E%28cos%28tan+x%29%29*cos%28sin%28tan+x%29%29+from+0+to+1.55) was$$\int_0^{1.55}e^{\cos\tan x}\cos\sin\tan xdx\approx2.24823.$$

Comment: @J.G. Force Alpha to come up with a decimal approximation using Mathematica's `N` function: [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5BIntegrate%5BExp%5BCos%5BTan%5Bx%5D%5D%5D*Cos%5BSin%5BTan%5Bx%5D%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CPi%2F2%7D%5D%5D) agrees with your answer.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks, I don't think I've seen that syntax used in WA before. Your link actually says $2.26942$, but that's close enough for my plausibility meter, especially given how difficult highly oscillatory integrands are for numerical algorithms.

Comment: @J.G. aschepler used Pi/2 rather than $1.55$ in their WA input. If you replace Pi/2 by $1.55$ you get your approximation.

Comment: @BrianTung Perhaps you do, but sadly $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{1/e}$ is less than the estimated value with upper limit $\pi/2$. Like I say, though, a relative error less than 1e-4 is believable.

Comment: @J.G. Oh absolutely yes. I'm not sure you can get closer easily with free tech. :-)

Comment: [PSQ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C40.7460) The area is greater than $\frac {\pi}{2e}$ since the function  is bounded between $e^{\pm1}$. Another idea is to make the $\cos(x)$ into it’s $e^{ix}$ form to have just $\int e^… dx+\int e^…dx $. Maybe something will simplify?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: Probably. I thought about closevoting it, but it seems unlikely to go much further at this point.

Comment: Rewriting as $\Re [\exp(\exp(i \tan(x)))]$ seems useful especially if one wants to apply resiude theorem

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints and explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [simpler form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+e%5E%28e%5E%28-i+tan%28x%29%29%29%2F2+%2B+e%5E%28e%5E%28i+tan%28x%29%29%29%2F2%3Dexp%28cos%28tan%28x%29%29%29cos%28sin%28tan%28x%29%29%29) of the integral: $$\frac12 \int_0^\frac\pi2 e^{e^{i\tan(x)}}dx+ \frac12 \int_0^\frac\pi2 e^{e^{-i\tan(x)}}dx=\text{Re}\int_0^\frac\pi2e^{e^{i\tan(x)}}dx$$

Now expand by using a series:

$$\text{Re}\int_0^\frac\pi2e^{e^{i\tan(x)}}dx = \text{Re}\int_0^\frac\pi2\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{in\tan(x)}}{n!}\right)dx$$

Using the [Ei function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+exp%28i+n+t%29%2F%28t%5E2%2B1%29), the substitution $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$, partial fractions, and integration to get:

$$\text{Re}\int_0^\frac\pi2\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{in\tan(x)}}{n!}\right)dx = \text{Re}\left(\frac\pi2-\frac i2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^n\text{Ei}((i\tan(x)-1)n)-e^{-n}\text{Ei}((i\tan(x)+1)n)}{n!}\right)\bigg|_0^\frac\pi2$$

taking limits for the evaluations:

$$\text{Re}\left(\frac\pi2-\frac i2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^n\text{Ei}((i\tan(x)-1)n)-e^{-n}\text{Ei}((i\tan(x)+1)n)}{n!}\right) = \text{Re}\left(\frac\pi2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi\sinh(n)-\frac12\left(e^n(i\text{Ei}(-n)+\pi\right)-ie^{-n}\text{Ei}(n))}{n!}\right)= \frac\pi2- \frac\pi2\left(e^e-\sqrt[e]e\right)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\pi e^n}{2n!}$$

which is checked [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi%2F2-sum%5B%28%CF%80+sinh%28n%29-%281%2F2+e%5En+%28%CF%80+%2B+i+Ei%28-n%29%29+-+1%2F2+i+e%5E%28-n%29+Ei%28n%29%29%29%2Fn%21%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C500%7D%5D). Now we verify @J.G.’s solution:

$$\boxed{\int_0^\frac\pi2e^{\cos(\tan(x))}\cos(\sin(\tan(x)))dx=\frac{\pi\sqrt[e]e}2}$$

However, the bonus $\int_0^\frac\pi2e^{\cos(\tan(x))}\sin(\sin(\tan(x)))dx$ has no closed form seen in the bolded link.